# Play Session Dropping during payment tracking

Tags: mysql, session, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a web app where when the user logs in i store the username in the session which is just a key/value pair attached in their cookies.

I am using Everbutton which is a 3rd party html button that allows easy Wepay payment processing. When a user clicks on the button to pay they are redirected through the Wepay process and then at the end they are then sent back to my site for confirmation.

My issue is that when they are redirected back to my site i am using the session to track who has paid and storing it in MySql. Whenever i test the feature it works fine but many users are getting errors where it can not find their session. Here is my login code and the payment processing code.

```
    def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
    loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors, null)),
      user => Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("email" -> user._1)
    )
  }

    def deposit(checkoutId: String) = Action {implicit request =>
    request.session.get("email").map { email =>
      User.findByEmail(email).map { user =>
        User.updateDeposit(user, checkoutId)
        Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("success" -> "We received your payment").withSession("email" -> user.email)
      }.getOrElse{
        Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("error" -> "We could not locate your account.Please contact walter.woodall.iv@gmail.com with the screen shot of your error").withSession("email" -> email)
      }
    }.getOrElse{
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("error" -> "We could not validate your session. Please contact walter.woodall.iv@gmail.com with the screen shot of your error")
    }
  }
```

Users must log in before they can pay so they should have a valid session.

I have been asking users about their browser and any plugins and what they did during payments. There is no pattern. People are getting the error on all browsers with no plugins. Really stuck here

Comment: Did you check that problem is not in the session timeout ?

Comment: From my understanding Play Session does not have timeout. Here is the documentation that says that https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash

Comment: Yes, but you can implement timeout, it's not clear from the question - maybe you implement it. As I understood from your response - you did not.

Comment: Maybe those users where the session doesn't survive the redirects have some kind of plugin installed that delete cookies? In how many percent of your users this happens?

Comment: AndriyKuba you are correct I did not implement a timeout. @Kris this is what I was thinking. I have a small user base 70 people but currently about 20% it is happening to. One person mentioned they were using no script with Firefox but others have been using chrome.

Comment: Mysterious! Do you have the possibility to check in the browser of those users where the session is lost, whether session-cookie is still there? Is it always the same users who loose there session - or do they mix?

Comment: I currently have them email me when they get the session error message but they are non technical users so I'm not sure if they can validate that their session is still there. And no not the same users. Completely random.

Comment: @AndriyKuba i was able to reproduce the error at random but its not making much sense. Most times it works but sometimes even when i check before i send the request that the cookie is there it comes back with the error and dropped cookie.