# Play Framework Date Parse Error

Tags: session, playframework, playframework-2.0, session-cookies

So i am having this issue with the play framework session dropping [Play Session Dropping during payment tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682998/play-session-dropping-during-payment-tracking?noredirect=1#comment53242127_32682998)

I recently checked my logs and notices this stack trace coming up frequently

```
    [debug] application - An invalidate date was received: Sat, 03 Oct 2015 23:08:37 UTC
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sat, 03 Oct 2015 23:08:37 UTC" is malformed at " UTC"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873) ~[joda-time.joda-time-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at controllers.AssetInfo$.parseDate(Assets.scala:106) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$controllers$AssetsBuilder$$maybeNotModified$3.apply(Assets.scala:326) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$controllers$AssetsBuilder$$maybeNotModified$3.apply(Assets.scala:325) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

I looked at this post on github (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3569) which is similar and says fixed but not sure if my version has the fix. I am using version 2.3.8.

Could this be causing my request to not have my session since it can not even parse the request?

Also do I need to update my version to fix this issue ?

Comment: [3569](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3569) References [3792](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3792) which doesn't have a milestone / hasn't been released. You can also check their [release page](https://www.playframework.com/changelog) and look for either 3569/3792. Until then, you could pull the [code fix](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3792/files) and try integrating it before it releases.